# how to resolve WebApplicationBuilder from a different app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Let's say I have an asp.net app with minimum setup

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

And I want to resolve the `app` so basically `var app = builder. Build();` from a different app (either console or asp.net). I had a look at [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.HostFactoryResolver/src/HostFactoryResolver.cs) but could not make it work, as it's resolving the build in an old way, can someone help me with this, or point me the correct direction thanks.

I want to access `app` from a different project. so after `builder. Build` and I want to access the service container, so WebApplication.Services Property, I want to resolve that container from a different app

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @montonero I want to access `app` from a different project.

Comment: Im not sure if that is what you want to do, but at the end of your program.cs 
add public partial class Program { }, this will allow you to use the program class in other places https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Could you please share why you would like to access app variable from another project?Because when you would try to access app variable of other project's program.cs file that would treat that as calller project program.cs file and would cause IO exception in using same port. So, would you kindly let us know why you want to do that.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I want to access the service container, so WebApplication.Services Property, I want to resolve that container from a different app.

Comment: I don't see how you could do this since the container belongs to this application. It would be easier if you elaborate on why you want to do this and what is the final goal.